# SQL query - Fetch data from one column separated by comma

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have problem with fetching data from one column separated with comma,

My problem is:

```
 Table1               
 ID | Cat          
--------
 1  | XY

 2  | ER

 3  | FF

Table2               
Id | Text | Text2 | Table1ID | Text3 | text3          
--------------------------------------------------
1  |  --  |  --   | 1,2,3    |  ---  | ---

2  |  --  |  --   | 3,1,2    |  ---  | ---

3  |  --  |  --   | 1,3,4    |  ---  | ---
```

I need SELECT query to fetch data from Table1 column Cat where  Table1.ID=Table2.Table1ID and i got only one Cat but i need all from Table2.Table1ID

This is my query now:

```
SELECT * FROM Table2, Table1 
        WHERE Table2.Table1ID=$ID 
        AND Table2.Table1ID=Table1.Id
        AND Table2.Table1ID
```

I only got one data from Table1ID and everything behind comma is invisible

thx for help

Comment: Splitting a string in SQL is a royal PITA. I think this was by design to stop people from storing data in comma delimited strings. So my first question would be: is this a production schema that you are working with, or do you have control of the schema so that you can change it to work in such a way that each id is stored in a separate record?

Comment: So much to say, so little time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Table2, Table1 
        WHERE Table1.Id=$ID 
        AND FIND_IN_SET(Table1.Id, Table2.Table1ID) <> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, sorry then. I misunderstood your explanation.

May not the better way but it may works:

`SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.Cat Like '%$ID,%' OR Table2.Cat Like '%,$ID'`

Comment: my variable $ID hold only one ID from Table1.ID
And i need all data from Table2.Table1ID 1,2,3 etc

thx for helping